# React Native CryptoJS Blocking the UI

Tags: react-native, encryption, base64, aes

Decryption using react-native-crypto-js blocking and freezing the UI until the decryption process finish.. any solution to solve this problem?

I'm decrypting using AES an image base64.

```
const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt( data, `password`);
const imageData = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: how did you solve this? using native code?

Comment: Actually I didn’t, i just resized and compressed the image before the encryption process, so its much faster now.